# jQuery, ajaxSetup, error and fail both executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following *ajaxSetup* configuration:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
                type: 'GET',
                headers: headers,
                error: function (data, par1, par2) {
                       //Error handling code here
                    }
            });
```

One of the members of my team wanted to handle errors in a different way in his *ajax* call

```
$.ajax({
                url: url,
            }).done(function (result) {
                //Success code here
            }).fail(function (e) {
                //Error handling code here
            });
```

The problem is that the error is getting handled in both sides, *error* (from ajaxSetup) and *fail*

To avoid double handling we add an empty *Error* function, like this

```
$.ajax({
                url: url,
                error: function () {},
                }).done(function (result) {
                    //Success code here
                }).fail(function (e) {
                    //Error handling code here
                });
```

But it seems a bit dirty, for my mind one of them should be executed not both, so my question is how should I configure my *ajaxSetup* in order to avoid this "issue"?

Comment: I fear that's just the way it works. The error property will define the default action and you can add additional handling via `fail()`. Overwriting the property, as you are doing, is a clean way to reset the default handler. It should be possible to set it to `null` instead of an empty anonymous function though.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42624210/1823841